# Putting frame around legend using QgsComposerLegend?

Tags: pyqgis

I can already see this being a simple answer but I'm stumped with this. I want to create a frame around a legend created by a PyQGIS script

Code snippet is:

```
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
c.addComposerLegend(legend)
legend.model().setLayerSet(map_settings.layerSet())
legend.setTitle('Clay %')
legend.setItemPosition(10,200, 0, 0)
legend.updateLegend()
c.addItem(legend)
```

I've looked through the API expecting to find something along the lines of legend.enableFrame() but am at a loss.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
legend.setFrameEnabled(True)
```

The relevant api docs are here http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerItem.html#a84db6541af98f47b090abf1860c0c8e6

Answer (score 1):

I used a function to get all possible methods (or constants) with the word 'frame' or 'Frame' in the class **QgsComposerLegend** (a list with 511 members). The result was:

1) With 'frame':

```
['frameChanged', 'frameJoinStyle', 'frameOutlineColor', 'frameOutlineWidth']
```

2) With 'Frame':

```
['ComposerFrame', 'drawFrame', 'estimatedFrameBleed', 'hasFrame', 'rectWithFrame', 
'setFrameEnabled', 'setFrameJoinStyle', 'setFrameOutlineColor', 'setFrameOutlineWidth']
```

I think that the possible method could be 'frameOutlineWidth' in the first list combined with several of the second list ('setFrameEnabled', 'setFrameOutlineWidth', 'drawFrame'). Test with them.